# How to fix a view inside ConstraintLayout while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `layout` which is scrollable. I need to a place a `ImageView` to the bottom right of the parent and the `ImageView` should be fixed to that position even while scrolling. Follow is the code I wrote.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/random_text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_to_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_to_top"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the `ImageView` is scrollable along with the content and not fixed. How to achieve this in `ConstraintLayout`? One solution will be to put `ImageView` outside the `ConstraintLayout`, but is there any where to achieve it while placing it inside `ConstraintLayout`.

**Note** : This is a very simple layout which I made up for posting the question. The real layout is more complex but has the same problem.

Comment: Wrap your scroll view with a frame layout and put the image view inside the frame layout below scroll view and set it's layout gravity to bottom

Comment: I think you are looking for either FAB (FloatingActionButton) or CoordinatorLayout.